# How to get a buddypress user profile link and a certain user profile field for the current post author?

Tags: buddypress, author, user-meta, profiles

I want to replace get_author_link() and get_the_author_meta($feld)

with something equivalent to point to the author of the current post Buddypress user profile page and retrieve a specific profile field from his Buddypress page

ie, I just want to show a link to the post user profile and a biography from one of his BP profile fields

I'm not sure which functions I should use for this... BuddyPress documentation is still not very clear unlike the WP Codex...

thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For an author's profile link, use

```
bp_core_get_user_domain( $user_id )
```

to get the URL, and

```
bp_core_get_userlink( $user_id )
```

to get an HTML link element, including display name.

For the xprofile data, use

```
xprofile_get_field_data( $field, $user_id )
```

`$field` can be either the name of the field (like 'Biography') or the numerical field id.

Answer (score 4):

It's kind of a bit different, but since this thread appears first on Google, it might be usefull for someone else.

To get the current logged-in user profile link, just use `bp_loggedin_user_domain()`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add it in comments:

```
    <?php
$author_id = get_comment(get_comment_ID())->user_id;
if (function_exists('bp_get_profile_field_data')) {
    $bp_name = bp_core_get_userlink( $author_id );
    $bp_location = bp_get_profile_field_data('field=Location&user_id='.$author_id);
    if ($bp_name) {
    echo '<div>'. $bp_name . '</div>';
    }
    if ($bp_location) {
    echo '<div class="authorinfo">'. $bp_location . '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

I included a sample profile field 'location', which may be removed.  This is for displaying a link to comment author's Buddypress profile.  It must be placed inside your comments loop, which will look something like:

```
foreach($comments as $comment)
```