# How to disable profile.php for users?

Tags: profiles

I am using wordpress 4.2.2 and i am using buddypress latest version. I want all my users customize their profile at buddypress profile page. So i want to disable profile.php for the users. I hide the profile link from dashboard by the WP admin UI customize plugin.But when anyone type url mysite/wp-admin/profile.php it's appear on browser.So i want to escape from the problem and want to disable profile.php for the users. What should i do to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Redirect from `profile.php` to the dashboard

Here's one way to do it:

```
add_action( 'load-profile.php', function() {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        exit( wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() ) );
} );
```

where we redirect to the dashboard instead, if the current user can't manage options.

### Redirect from `profile.php` to the current user's member page

If you want to redirect to the member's profile page, you could try (untested):

```
add_action( 'load-profile.php', function() {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && function_exists( 'bp_core_get_user_domain' ) )
        exit( wp_safe_redirect( bp_core_get_user_domain( get_current_user_id() ) ) );
} );
```

The `bp_core_get_user_domain()` function is mentioned in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45345/26350), few years ago, by @BooneGorges.

I just checked the BP [source](https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/2.3/src/bp-members/bp-members-functions.php#L153-192) and this function is still available in BP 2.3 (see [here](https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/2.3/src/bp-members/bp-members-functions.php#L153-192)).

### For PHP < 5.3

```
add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'wpse_195353_profile_redirect_to_dashboard' );
function wpse_195353_profile_redirect_to_dashboard()
{
    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        exit( wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() ) );
}
```

and

```
add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'wpse_195353_profile_redirect_to_member_page' );
function wpse_195353_profile_redirect_to_member_page()
{
    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && function_exists( 'bp_core_get_user_domain' ) )
        exit( wp_safe_redirect( bp_core_get_user_domain( get_current_user_id() ) ) );
}
```

but you should consider updating your PHP if that's the case.

Comment: This is not helping brother. When i paste those two codes it is showing white screen.

Comment: Are you using PHP < 5.3 ? If so then the anonymous functions aren´t supported, but it's easy to change that to normal functions - please check out the updated answer  @azizul

Comment: Brother! The two codes for PHP<5.3 is workinkg !! But there is a problem that my server(bluehost) cPanel showing PHP version 5.4.24 I don't know why this code is working. Is there any problem will be happen in future if i use this code?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. That's strange but both code versions should be PHP future safe. I just like the anonymous functions, introduced in PHP 5.3 ;-) @azizul

Comment: Thank's a lot for above help. I want another help! I want to redirect **admin.php?page=jetpack** also for users. How to do that?

Comment: Maybe that is better served as a new question? @azizul

Comment: +1, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The following code* will redirect non-admin to a custom profile page in the front end, because instead of disabling you need to redirect them to your custom page. :)

```
<?php
add_action ('init' , 'wpse_redirect_profile_access');

function wpse_redirect_profile_access(){
        //admin won't be affected
        if (current_user_can('manage_options')) return '';

        //if we're at admin profile.php page
        if (strpos ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] , 'wp-admin/profile.php' )) {
            wp_redirect ( home_url( '/my-profile' )); // to page like: example.com/my-profile/
            exit();
        }

}
```

*[Source^](http://blog.happyplugins.com/redirect-user-profile-page-frontend-page/)

Comment: It looks like there's a missing `exit();`, after the redirect part.

Comment: @birgire you are right. I din't notice that, thanks a lot. Fixed now. :)

Comment: ps: we must be careful using `if` without curly braces. It works for a single expression but you got two. Currently the `exit()` is outside the `if` part and will always run. So we better use the `if(){ }` syntax  when dealing with two or more expressions ;-)

Comment: @birgire I missed that again. Thanks a lot again. :)

Answer (score 1):

I like this one. You can add admin pages to the array to redirect them. I have it redirecting to the Dashboard below, but you can redirect to BuddyPress URL as well... I'm just not sure what that URL is since I don't use BP very often.

```
   function no_proflie_admin_pages_redirect() {
      global $pagenow;
      if(!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
          $admin_redirects = array(
                    'profile.php'
                );
          if(in_array($pagenow, $admin_redirects)){
            wp_redirect( admin_url('/') ); exit;
          }
      }
    }
    add_action('admin_init', 'no_proflie_admin_pages_redirect');
```

**You can also hide any additional profile.php links with simple CSS:**

```
function hide_any_profile_links() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        a[href="http://example.com/wp-admin/profile.php"], a[href="profile.php"]{
            display: none!important;
        }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_any_profile_links', 999);
```

The above could also be achieved with jquery or using PHP and the output buffer.

Comment: I'm afraid it will not work to have `current_user_can()` in the global scope, because of `wp_get_current_user()` not beeing defined yet.

Comment: Hey @birgire, could you give example of when this would not work with profile page?

Comment: The `current_user_can()` check should be inside the `no_proflie_admin_pages_redirect ` callback, to avoid the undefined error.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response birgire, I just noticed. Anyway, do you know of specifically when this might actually happen? I've been doing it this way for a couple years now and haven't run into any issues and surprisingly have never run into an issue or seen any error messages... Would this occur only for certain users?

Comment: We can't use `current_user_can()` in the global scope, within a plugin. This leads to `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()`. But I guess you use it within the `functions.php` file?

Comment: You were right. Tested this in in a plugin as opposed to `functions.php` and I got the fatal error!

Comment: The CSS selector can be simplified to `a[href$="profile.php"]`, which means matches the end of the `href` attribute value.

Comment: Great call @Raptor

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @birgire 's answer, from which I found the first snippet to be the cleanest one I've seen for this, I wanted to add the following since I think it might be useful for most people arriving to this thread.

**If you don't want users to access their profile on the backend, you will most probably also don't want them to be able to access the dashboard.**

The use case is when you have subscribers that you don't want to access the backend at all. By default they can access the dashboard and their profile, so let's avoid that:

```php
function redirect_subscribers () {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        exit( wp_safe_redirect( site_url() ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'load-index.php', 'redirect_subscribers' );
add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'redirect_subscribers' );
```

Notice that in this case I've used the `edit_posts` capability, since I'm only targeting subscribers and [this is a capability all roles have except for subscribers](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

Then I'm using `site_url()` to redirect them to the homepage, but you could also use `get_permalink($page_id)` using the `id` of the page where you have created a "My account" area as a parameter.

The `load-{$page_hook}` is [documented in codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/).